# importing a module from a folder within parent directory

Tags: python, import, directory

I want to import a module from a folder within the parent directory.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
folder
     analyse
          analysis1.py
     modules
          analyses
          functions.py
```

Where functions.py contains a function called function1. When I run analysis1.py, I want to import this function.

Currently, I use the following:

```
import os 
os.chdir("..")
from modules.analyses.functions import function1
```

However, this is not my preferred method to import this function. Is there any other method to do so? I also tried to import by using:

```
from ..modules.analyses.functions import function1
```

But then I get the error message:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sys` module to add the parent directory to system path.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "..")
from modules.analyses.functions import function1
```